# How can i add custom header fields while uploading file into Amazon s3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to store multimedia files in Amazons3.

I used the following code for uploading a the file.

**Method 1:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AbortMultipartUploadRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CompleteMultipartUploadResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PartETag;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ProgressEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ProgressListener;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.UploadPartRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.UploadPartResult;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AmazonUploader {

    private static final long MIN_DEFAULT_PART_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

    private static final String TAG = "AmazonUploader";
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "preferences_simpl3r";
    private static final String PREFS_UPLOAD_ID = "_uploadId";
    private static final String PREFS_ETAGS = "_etags";
    private static final String PREFS_ETAG_SEP = "~~";

    private AmazonS3Client s3Client;
    private String s3bucketName;
    private String s3key;
    private File file;

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private long partSize = MIN_DEFAULT_PART_SIZE;
    private UploadProgressListener progressListener;
    private long bytesUploaded = 0;
    private boolean userInterrupted = false;
    private boolean userAborted = false;

    public AmazonUploader(Context context, AmazonS3Client s3Client, String s3bucketName, String s3key, File file) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
        this.s3key = s3key;
        this.s3bucketName = s3bucketName;
        this.file = file;
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * Initiate a multipart file upload to Amazon S3
     *
     * @return the URL of a successfully uploaded file
     */
    public String start() {

        // initialize
        List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
        final long contentLength = file.length();
        long filePosition = 0;
        int startPartNumber = 1;

        userInterrupted = false;
        userAborted = false;
        bytesUploaded = 0;

        // check if we can resume an incomplete download
        String uploadId = getCachedUploadId();

        if (uploadId != null) {
            // we can resume the download
            Log.i(TAG, "resuming upload for " + uploadId);

            // get the cached etags
            List<PartETag> cachedEtags = getCachedPartEtags();
            partETags.addAll(cachedEtags);

            // calculate the start position for resume
            startPartNumber = cachedEtags.size() + 1;
            filePosition = (startPartNumber - 1) * partSize;
            bytesUploaded = filePosition;

            Log.i(TAG, "resuming at part " + startPartNumber + " position " + filePosition);

        } else {
            // initiate a new multi part upload
            Log.i(TAG, "initiating new upload");

            InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(s3bucketName, s3key);
//            ObjectMetadata obj = new ObjectMetadata();
//            obj.setContentType("image/jpeg");
//            obj.setHeader(Constants.APP_HEADER_REFERER, Constants.APP_REFERER_URL);
//            initRequest.setObjectMetadata(obj);


            configureInitiateRequest(initRequest);
            InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
            uploadId = initResponse.getUploadId();

        }

        final AbortMultipartUploadRequest abortRequest = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest(s3bucketName, s3key, uploadId);

        for (int k = startPartNumber; filePosition < contentLength; k++) {

            long thisPartSize = Math.min(partSize, (contentLength - filePosition));

            Log.i(TAG, "starting file part " + k + " with size " + thisPartSize);

            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest().withBucketName(s3bucketName)
                    .withKey(s3key).withUploadId(uploadId)
                    .withPartNumber(k).withFileOffset(filePosition).withFile(file)
                    .withPartSize(thisPartSize);

            ProgressListener s3progressListener = new ProgressListener() {
                public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {

                    // bail out if user cancelled
                    // TODO calling shutdown too brute force?
                    if (userInterrupted) {
                        s3Client.shutdown();
                        throw new UploadIterruptedException("User interrupted");
                    } else if (userAborted) {
                        // aborted requests cannot be resumed, so clear any cached etags
                        clearProgressCache();
                        s3Client.abortMultipartUpload(abortRequest);
                        s3Client.shutdown();
                    }

                    bytesUploaded += progressEvent.getBytesTransfered();

                    //Log.d(TAG, "bytesUploaded=" + bytesUploaded);

                    // broadcast progress
                    float fpercent = ((bytesUploaded * 100) / contentLength);
                    int percent = Math.round(fpercent);
                    if (progressListener != null) {
                        progressListener.progressChanged(progressEvent, bytesUploaded, percent);
                    }

                }
            };

            uploadRequest.setProgressListener(s3progressListener);

            UploadPartResult result = s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest);
            partETags.add(result.getPartETag());

            // cache the part progress for this upload
            if (k == 1) {
                initProgressCache(uploadId);
            }
            // store part etag
            cachePartEtag(result);

            filePosition += thisPartSize;
        }

        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(
                s3bucketName, s3key, uploadId,
                partETags);

        CompleteMultipartUploadResult result = s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
        bytesUploaded = 0;

        Log.i(TAG, "upload complete for " + uploadId);

        clearProgressCache();

        return result.getLocation();

    }

    private String getCachedUploadId() {
        return prefs.getString(s3key + PREFS_UPLOAD_ID, null);
    }

    private List<PartETag> getCachedPartEtags() {
        List<PartETag> result = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
        // get the cached etags
        ArrayList<String> etags = SharedPreferencesUtils.getStringArrayPref(prefs, s3key + PREFS_ETAGS);
        for (String etagString : etags) {
            String partNum = etagString.substring(0, etagString.indexOf(PREFS_ETAG_SEP));
            String partTag = etagString.substring(etagString.indexOf(PREFS_ETAG_SEP) + 2, etagString.length());

            PartETag etag = new PartETag(Integer.parseInt(partNum), partTag);
            result.add(etag);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void cachePartEtag(UploadPartResult result) {
        String serialEtag = result.getPartETag().getPartNumber() + PREFS_ETAG_SEP + result.getPartETag().getETag();
        ArrayList<String> etags = SharedPreferencesUtils.getStringArrayPref(prefs, s3key + PREFS_ETAGS);
        etags.add(serialEtag);
        SharedPreferencesUtils.setStringArrayPref(prefs, s3key + PREFS_ETAGS, etags);
    }

    private void initProgressCache(String uploadId) {
        // store uploadID
        Editor edit = prefs.edit().putString(s3key + PREFS_UPLOAD_ID, uploadId);
        AmazonSharedPreferencesCompact.apply(edit);
        // create empty etag array
        ArrayList<String> etags = new ArrayList<String>();
        SharedPreferencesUtils.setStringArrayPref(prefs, s3key + PREFS_ETAGS, etags);
    }

    private void clearProgressCache() {
        // clear the cached uploadId and etags
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.remove(s3key + PREFS_UPLOAD_ID);
        edit.remove(s3key + PREFS_ETAGS);
        AmazonSharedPreferencesCompact.apply(edit);
    }

    public void interrupt() {
        userInterrupted = true;
    }

    public void abort() {
        userAborted = true;
    }

    /**
     * Override to configure the multipart upload request.
     * <p/>
     * By default uploaded files are publicly readable.
     *
     * @param initRequest S3 request object for the file to be uploaded
     */
    protected void configureInitiateRequest(InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest) {
        initRequest.setCannedACL(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        ObjectMetadata obj = new ObjectMetadata();
        obj.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        obj.setHeader(Constants.APP_HEADER_REFERER, Constants.APP_REFERER_URL);
        initRequest.withObjectMetadata(obj);
    }

    public void setPrefs(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        this.prefs = prefs;
    }

    public long getPartSize() {
        return partSize;
    }

    public void setPartSize(long partSize) {
        if (partSize < MIN_DEFAULT_PART_SIZE) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Part size is less than S3 minimum of " + MIN_DEFAULT_PART_SIZE);
        } else {
            this.partSize = partSize;
        }
    }

    public void setProgressListener(UploadProgressListener progressListener) {
        this.progressListener = progressListener;
    }

    public interface UploadProgressListener {
        public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent, long bytesUploaded, int percentUploaded);
    }

}
```

**Method 2:**

```
TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
        Constants.S3_BUCKET_NAME,     /* The bucket to upload to */
        fileName,    /* The key for the uploaded object */
        new File(imagePath),       /* The file where the data to upload exists */
        objectMetadata);

transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
```

in both method i got the following error

```
 com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request...
```

Here i must pass customer header parameters, so i add like following

```
 ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        HashMap<String, String> mMetaMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mMetaMap.put("content-type", "image/jpeg");
        mMetaMap.put(Constants.APP_HEADER_REFERER, Constants.APP_REFERER_URL);
        objectMetadata.setUserMetadata(mMetaMap);
```

But still i got the above error.

Is i'm passing the header parameters in correct way either i need to do changes. Kindly advise on this. Thanks

Comment: 403 is generally an access issue problem. Have you checked whether you have the right access?

Comment: @Shibashis: Thanks, let me know whether i'm adding header in correct way

Comment: for setting content type, you should use `setContentType` method of ObjectMetadata class

Comment: setUserMetadata  is for setting the custom user-metadata for the associated object

Comment: @Shibashis Yes i added but same issuse.. also, i used CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider for authentication - while i debugging it show another pool-id.

Comment: As Shibashis mention, the 403 problem is probably not due to adding new headers. check that you can access S3 without modifying any headers, do you still get the same 403? Have you checked the ACL on the bucket, IAM role/policy?